# Accessing Dropwizard config from Initialize()?

Tags: dropwizard

I am trying to create a scheduled job for Dropwizard that rans every minute and queries a database for values.

For that to work I need to register some DAOs and a service in the `initialize()` stage, like so:

```
@Override
public void initialize(final Bootstrap<KMDServiceConfiguration> bootstrap) {

    //JDBI
    final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
    final DateTimeArgumentFactory dateTimeFactory = new DateTimeArgumentFactory();
    final DBI jdbi = factory
            .build(environment, config.getDataSourceFactory(), "kmd");
    jdbi.registerArgumentFactory(dateTimeFactory);

    //DAOs
    final UserDao userDao = jdbi.onDemand(UserDao.class);
    final NotificationDao notificationDao = jdbi.onDemand(NotificationDao.class);

    //Domain services
    final UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl(userDao);
    final NotificationService notificationService = new NotificationServiceImpl(notificationDao);

    final MessageService messageService = new MessageServiceImpl(userService, notificationService);


    final Job worker= new MessageWorker(messageService);
    bootstrap.addBundle(new JobsBundle(worker));
```

JDBI requires the Dropwizard `environment` and the configuration object.

Is it possible to access these at this stage so that my dependencies can be properly setup?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to initialize the job from the "run" method in the DW Application class, which has access to the configuration and environment attributes. I have put together a simple [project](https://github.com/andremanuelbarbosa/SOQ49638642) to show this but this is how the run method looks like:

```
@Override
public void run(SOQ49638642Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {

    final DBI dbi = (new DBIFactory()).build(environment, configuration.getDataSourceFactory(), "kmd");

    final SOQ49638642Job soq49638642Job = new SOQ49638642Job(new SOQ49638642Service(dbi.onDemand(SOQ49638642Dao.class)));

    final JobsBundle jobsBundle = new JobsBundle(soq49638642Job);

    jobsBundle.run(configuration, environment);
}
```

As far as I know, it is not possible to get those objects in the "initialize" phase. You can also have a look at Guice integrations for DW like [dropwizard-guicey](https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey) which provide nice mechanisms for DI of Bundles and Modules in DW.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try later, I wonder why in their examples they use the `Initialize() `phase?

Comment: That is a good question @tomaytotomato. The examples listed are only possible for simple job classes which are not dependant on the configuration or environment, which is not true most of the use cases.